# 3D graphics in manipulate with preset ViewPoint

Tags: graphics3d, manipulate

I would like to have a `Manipulate` with one binary control. The output should be either a 3D graphic with a dynamically shown `ViewPoint` (so it updates when I rotate the 3D graphic) or the view of the graphic with preset `ViewPoint`. My attempt was along the following lines:

```mathematica
Module[{vp = OptionValue[Graphics3D, ViewPoint]},
 Manipulate[
  Row[{
    ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[a], Sin[a], z}, {a, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {z, 0, 1}, 
     ViewPoint -> Which[view == "dynamic", Dynamic[vp], view == "static", {0, 1, 0}]],
    If[view == "dynamic", Dynamic[vp]]
    }],
  {{view, "static"}, {"dynamic", "static"}}
  ]]
```

I attempted to use `Switch` and `Piecewise` too. The issue is that once I move the graphic, it breaks down. If I move the graphic when the control is `dynamic`, the graphic will not be reset to given `ViewPoint` when I switch to `static` afterwards (which I would like it to do). When I move the graphic when the control is `static` and go to `dynamic`, the `ViewPoint` coordinates are not updated and when I switch back to `static` also the graphic does not react.

Could you show me a way how to retain all the required functionality even after interacting with the 3D graphic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your approach doesn't work is the following: Since the top-level wrapper of the `ViewPoint` setting is not `Dynamic`, the setting is replaced with the updated value of the `ViewPoint`. This means that all your logic is discarded as soon as the user drags around the graphic.

Here is an approach to achieve what you describe:

```
Manipulate[
 Row[
  {
   ParametricPlot3D[
    {Cos[a], Sin[a], z}, {a, -π, π}, {z, 0, 1},
    ViewPoint -> 
      Dynamic[If[view == "dynamic", vp, {0, 1, 0}],  If[view == "dynamic", vp = #] &],
    ImageSize -> 200
    ],
   If[view == "dynamic", Dynamic[vp]]
   }
  ],
 {{vp, OptionValue[Graphics3D, ViewPoint]}, None},
 {{view, "static"}, {"dynamic", "static"}}
 ]
```

[image]

Some notes:

- I add `vp` as a `Manipulate` variable instead of a `Module` variable to make sure it's properly preserved together with the rest of the `Manipulate`
- The `ViewPoint` setting now has a single top-level `Dynamic` wrapper
- To prevent the user from changing it in "static" mode, I provide a custom setter function that is called whenever the user interactively tries to modify the `ViewPoint`. Since we just ignore the attempt to update the value when we're in static mode, the user can't change it.

Comment: Thank you. Works as requested. Marked as an answer. Somewhat surprising how Mathematica works sometimes :) If I do this also for the ViewVertical, I can force the graphic to be nonrotable :D